# Custom notification layouts

Tags: android, styles

I try to create resources like

res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="NotificationTitle">
      <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NotificationText">
      <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

res/values-v9/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="NotificationText" parent="android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" />
    <style name="NotificationTitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title" />
</resources>
```

But for values-v9 I get this error:

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title'.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's caused by the error format of the parent attribute.
try

```
<style name="NotificationText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" />
    <style name="NotificationTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title" />
```

Comment: thank you but i get the same: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent'.

Comment: I forget there is a '@' before android. Try using `parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set your target API (different from the target SDK) in the Project Properties (not the manifest) to be at least 2.3.3 (API 10).